# Swift enum conformance to Equatable when result type used as associated value: Type doesn't conform to protocol Equatable

Tags: swift, enums

```
struct Book: Equatable {
    var book: String
}

enum BookAction: Equatable {
    case dataResponse(Result<Book, Error>)
}
```

I'm running swift version 5.6.1. I'm trying to understand why I'm getting an error that "type 'BookAction' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'". While I can get it to work if I add a `static func == (lhs: BoockAction, rhs: BookAction) -> Bool` to the enum, I thought that the compiler would generate the equatable code behind the scenes like it does for the struct Book. It seems like it has everything needed to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enum can automatically conform to `Equatable` if its associated values conform to `Equatable`, from docs:

> For an enum, all its associated values must conform to Equatable. (An enum without associated values has Equatable conformance even without the declaration.)

And the `Result<Success, Failure>` only conforms to `Equatable` when

> `Success` conforms to `Equatable`, `Failure` conforms to `Equatable`, and `Failure` conforms to `Error`.

Your result's failure is only conform to `Error` and `Error` is not `Equatable` yet. You can try to replace your `Error` with a type that conforms to both `Error` and `Equatable`

```
enum BookAction: Equatable {
    case dataResponse(Result<Book, ActionError>)
}

struct ActionError: Error, Equatable { }
```

Ref:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks.